# Xcode shortcut to display the error on current line

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a vim user and while programming on XCode, I am a big fan of XVim. It would be super awesome if I could also display the syntax error for the line my cursor is on. I would pretty much never have to use the mouse. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Jump to Next Issue*(`Cmd + '`) or *Jump to Previous Issue*(`Cmd + "`).